# Add to Cart from Wishlist not working

Tags: magento-1.9, wishlist, addtocart

Maybe something is amiss with my Theme - but when I go into Wishlist and choose "add to cart" next to the item in the wishlist, nothing happens. No error or anything like that. You just click it and nothing happens.

Is this a form-key issue? Add to cart works everywhere else on the site it is just from the wishlist that this does not work. Also the "Add all to cart" function in the Wishlist works perfectly.

Thanks!

[image: add to cart not working]
<sub>(source: [premierlightbulbs.com](https://premierlightbulbs.com/skin/frontend/default/mobileshoppe/images/add-to-cart-button-not-working.png))</sub>

Comment: have you tried "add all to cart" button to check if that works?

Comment: Yep that works perfect - adds all products to the cart.

Comment: seems javascript of "add to cart" button is either missing or failing due to some error. Can you check in firebug console to see if there is any error?

Comment: It says "> Uncaught ReferenceError: addWItemToCart is not defined  (index) : 245"

Comment: Your javascript function "addWItemToCart" is missing in that page which is responsible to add item from wishlist to cart.

Comment: http://files.magentochina.org/nav.html?app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/view.phtml.source.html

Comment: So are you suggesting I replace my app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/view.phtml file with the one you linked to? (while backing up my existing one obviously).

Comment: No add the javascript functions to your custom theme file located at that path. Seems your custom theme file is missing those JS functions which are required.

Comment: Hmm. I don't even have view.phtml at app/design/frontend/default/mobileshoppe/template/wishlist . Maybe that explains it, I don't even have the file there at all?

Comment: Just copy the file over there then, that should solve the problem.

Comment: I added the missing javascript that was in my app/design/frontend/default/mobileshoppe/template/wishlist/view.phtml file and nothing changed. Even after full copying nothing changed and Add to Cart still doesn't work.

Comment: Okay after some more testing I fixed it! My theme doesn't even look at the view.phtml in the base folder so I had to just paste the missing javascript I had into one of the wishlist cart files. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add form key on wishlist add to cart form

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey');?>
```

Comment: So I add that somewhere on app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/view.phtml??  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my theme MobileShoppe does not even look at view.phtml in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist. So I had to add the javascript from view.phtml into cart.html in the wishlist template folder of my theme... and now it adds the items to the cart as it should. Thanks to everyone who helped provide solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code into the javascript section of `app/design/frontend/[yourtheme]/[yourtheme]/template/wishlist/view.phtml`

```
    function addWItemToCart(itemId) {
    var url = '<?php echo $this->getItemAddToCartUrl('%item%') ?>';
    url = url.gsub('%item%', itemId);
    var form = $('wishlist-view-form');
    if (form) {
        var input = form['qty[' + itemId + ']'];
        if (input) {
            var separator = (url.indexOf('?') >= 0) ? '&' : '?';
            url += separator + input.name + '=' + encodeURIComponent(input.value);
        }
    }
    setLocation(url);
}
```